# How to generate RGB images of the same size as a tiff file using its .shp file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, geopandas

**1. Existing data:**

I have some remote sensing image data of an area, their names are "xx, BPW", "xx. TFW", **"xx. tif"**, "xx. Tif. Aux. XML", "xx. tif. Ovr", "xx. DBF", "xx. PRJ", "xx. SBN", "xx. SBX", **"xx. shp"**, "xx. The SHP. XML", "xx. SHS" respectively. **There are many features exist in .shp file, but I just use one of them.**

The .tif remote sensing image and corresponding .shp file can be correctly visualized in GIS software, and their coordinates are strictly the same.

**2. Problem description**

**I am a computer science student and have little knowledge of remote sensing data, I want to use the .shp file to generate a RGB label image that can be used for semantic segmentation task in deep learning (i.e. each value in a chosen feature will be visualized in one color), and the size of RGB label image can fully match the size of the .tif file. However, the size of label I generated now is different from .tif file, which does not meet my needs, and I have no idea how to fix it.**

**3. What I have done**

3.1 Generate label image

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import gdal
import numpy as np

tiff_file = "xx.tif"
shp_file = "xx.shp"
png_file = "xx.png"
variable = "OneFeature"

#open shp file
gp_file = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shp_file)
#convert to plt image
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.axis('off')
gp_file.plot(column=variable, cmap='Blues', ax=ax)
#save label image to png file
fig.savefig(png_file, dpi=200)
```

Then I got this image:
[image: My Generated Label]

3.2 Get the size of the tif file

```
tif = gdal.Open(tiff_file)  # (30480, 43990, 3)
print("tif.RasterCount =", tif.RasterCount)  # 3
band1 = tif.GetRasterBand(1)
band2 = tif.GetRasterBand(2)
band3 = tif.GetRasterBand(3)
band1Array = band1.ReadAsArray()
band1Array = band1Array[:, :, np.newaxis]
band2Array = band2.ReadAsArray()
band2Array = band2Array[:, :, np.newaxis]
band3Array = band3.ReadAsArray()
band3Array = band3Array[:, :, np.newaxis]
tifArray = tif.ReadAsArray()
print(tif)

band3d = np.concatenate((band1Array, band2Array, band3Array), axis=2)
print(band1Array.shape)
print(band3d.shape)
```

The tif file is too large (~4GB) so I didn't visualize it in Python.

Now, the size of tif is (30480, 43990, 3) but the size of generated label is (960, 1280, 3). Obviously they have different aspect ratios. **How can I generate I label image with size of (30480, 43990, 3) meanwhile make the ground objects in the tif and PNG image in the same pixel place? (for example if a tree's coordinate in tif file is (301,400), its coordinate in label image should also be (301,400))**

> **Or, is there another way to convert .shp file into a label image easily?**

Comment: Can you share an example of a relatively simple shape file and say what size it currently is and what size you want it to become please?